# ¿Cómo poner Marker estático sobre el mapa y mostrar coordenadas según mueva el mapa?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

¿Cómo puedo poner mi Marker estático encima del mapa y que me muestre las coordenadas según mueva el mapa?

Si bien existe el draggable: true, para poder mover el marker  y obtener las nuevas coordenadas lo que quisiera es lo contrario que el marker sea Stack(centrado en mi Ubicacion) y cuando mueva el mapa me de las nuevas coordenadas

// Crear Marker

```
  createMarkers() {
    markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("MarkerCurrent"),
        position: currentLocation,
        icon: icon,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: "Mi Ubicacion",
            snippet:
                "Lat ${currentLocation.latitude} - Lng ${currentLocation.longitude}"),
        draggable: true,
        onDragEnd: onDragEnd,
      ),
    );
  }


onDragEnd(LatLng position) {
    print("nueva posiion $position");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si estas usando el packages goggle_maps_flutter tiene una propiedad que es OnCameraMove que mientras vas moviendo el mapa obtiene las coordenadas del centro, una ves que se detiene el movimiento se activa onCameraIdle aquí es donde puedes llamar a tu función para que muestre en pantalla las nuevas coordenadas del centro obtenidas de CameraPosition(target).

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';


class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MapSample> createState() => MapSampleState();
}

class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
String finallat="";
String finalong="";
bool buscando=false;
  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );


   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
           Positioned(
             top: 0,
             child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
               child:GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        onCameraMove:(CameraPosition camerapos){
          buscando=false;
          setState(() {

          });
         finallat=camerapos.target.latitude.toString();
         finalong=camerapos.target.longitude.toString();
        },
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);

        },
        onCameraIdle: (){
          buscando=true;
          setState(() {

          });
          //POSICION DEL CENTRO AL DETENERSE el MOVIMIENTO
              print("=========latitud centro final ="+finallat);
              print("=========logitud centro final= "+finalong);
        },
      ),
          ),
        ),
         Align(
         alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Icon(Icons.location_on,size: 50,color: Colors.redAccent,),
      ),
        buscando==true?Positioned(
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.4,
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,
                  child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          width: 200,
          height: 50,
          child: Text("$finallat ; $finalong"),
          ),
        ): 
          Positioned(
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.4,
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,
                  child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 100,
            height: 50,
            child: Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator()),
          ),
        )
        ],
      )

    );
  }


}
```

Comment: Bien, gracias lo estoy probando, ahora me surgió otro inconveniente al no ser un marker como tal como pongo el infowindow ( un CircularProgressIndicator y luego las cordenadas. )

Comment: acabo e editar la repuesta , agregue un container con la latitud y longitud para que simule el infowindow y cuando se realiza el movimiento cambia a un CircularProgressIndicator

Comment: le puedes poner al container del CircularProgressIndicator un padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),

Comment: @ConstantedePlanck si l apublicación resolvió el problema, por favor márquela como solución a la pregunta.